# Merging two large dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, large-data

How should i merge the `label` column in dataframe `df`(8 million rows) to another dataframe `df2` (143 million rows) when the data size is that large?

Basically I just want to map the `label` column to `df2`, all the data in `df` is included in `df2` except the `label` column. Is there anyway I can solve this issue instead of using `merge()`?

Tried to run the code below, but it keeps running for 5 hours but has no response.

```
result = pd.merge(df,df2,on=["X", "Y", "Z"], how='left')
result
```

df

[image]

df2

[image]

Comment: I think this is task for some DB, if need python dask or some alternatives. In pure pandas need large memory...

Comment: @jezrael Actually this is point cloud data, each row represents one data point. Would you recommend to use relational database / noSQL database to work on it?

Comment: Unfortuantely i have no experience, so cannot :(

Comment: @jezrael no worries, thank you :) !

Answer (score 1):

The are a few of obvious things I can see here that you can do:

1. Assuming you just want to add the label based on the `X`/`Y`/`Z` columns and `R`/`G`/`B` are superfluous, then drop the `R`/`G`/`B` columns of `df` as you don't need them in the final data frame, and you certainly don't need them being duplicated 143 million times.
2. Depending on how many unique values of `X`/`Y`/`Z` and their data type, you may be able to reduce the memory footprint by using categorical data types like so:

```py
# Convert to categorical data types (if every value is unique, don't bother!)
for df_temp in [df, df2]:
    for col in ['X', 'Y', 'Z']:
        df_temp.loc[:, col] = df_temp[col].astype('category')
# Merge using less memory
result = pd.merge(df, df2, on=["X", "Y", "Z"], how='left')
```

3. Finally, you can try partitioning the data and doing a destructive conversion, you create several data frames each containing `X` in non-overlapping ranges and process them individually, then concatenate the individual results to give you the final result, e.g.:

```py
result_dfs = []
ranges = [0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, ...]
for start, end in zip(ranges[:-1], ranges[1:]):
    df_idx = (df['X'] >= start) & (df['X'] < end)
    df2_idx = (df2['X'] >= start) & (df2['X'] < end)
    result_dfs.append(
        pd.merge(
            df[df_idx], 
            df2[df2_idx], 
            on=["X", "Y", "Z"], 
            how='left'
        )
    )
    # Remove the original data to to reduce memory consumption
    df2 = df2[~df2_idx]
result = pd.concat(result_dfs)
```

This may still not work though, as you still need the full data set in memory twice for a short while when you do the final concatenation!

If none of these work, I'm afraid you need more memory, or you need to use something other than Pandas to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you sir @Chris-Cooper for advising a detailed solution. Actually this is a point cloud data and each row presents a data point. Therefore each XYZ of a row are unique values however I couldn't drop the RGB columns in order to keep the completeness of dataset. I think in this case I shouldn't expect Pandas can do this job for me.. Would you recommend I should manipulate the data in database / other way?

Comment: In that case, you are probably better off loading this in a database and doing the join there using SQL.